# Is there any disadvantage to make all the instance methods an arrow function, to avoid lost bindings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Is there any disadvantage to make all the instance methods an arrow function?  This way, we don't have the "lost binding" issue.

So for example, the following has the lost binding issue.  We don't usually write code to invoke `this.foo()` this way, but in ReactJS, for example, we use `onClick={this.foo}`, which translates to `createElement({ ..., onclick: this.foo, ...})`, so there is lost binding right there.

```js
class Dog {

    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    giveSound() {
        console.log(`${this.name} says woof`);
    }

    giveAlert() {
        console.log("I am alert");
        const f = this.giveSound;
        f();
    }

}

const woofie = new Dog("woofie");

woofie.giveSound();

woofie.giveAlert();
```

So if everything is an arrow function, then there is no such worry:

```js
class Dog {

    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    giveSound = () => {
        console.log(`${this.name} says woof`);
    }

    giveAlert = () => {
        console.log("I am alert");
        const f = this.giveSound;
        f();
    }

}

const woofie = new Dog("woofie");

woofie.giveSound();

woofie.giveAlert();
```

But is there any disadvantage?

Comment: The disadvantage is that every instance gets its own copy of the function. If you don't have many instances, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of disadvantages, but as you've pointed out, there's also an advantage, so it's really up to you.

The two main disadvantages I'm aware of are:

1. Every instance gets its own function objects for each method (three months = three function objects per instance), rather than sharing via the prototype. That means:

   - You create a bunch more objects when you create the instance (the function *code* is shared, but each instance gets its own function objects), and
   - Inheriting may be trickier
2. It makes the methods harder to mock for testing purposes, because they're not on the prototype, they're built into each instance.

Comment: so it is like a variable... getting assigned a newly created function object... I guess in the case of ReactJS Components, there may be 1 or a few such components on the page, so it is not a big deal. Or else some people do this in constructor `this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);`

Comment: @nonopolarity Most of the React developers does not uses class components now days. Instead they uses functional components with hooks. So technically we don't have a problem with `this` in React js now. So non of the components are going to end up with having many arrow functions and also there are techniques, hooks to improve the performances and stop re declaring those functions again and again when ui updates.

Comment: @nonopolarity - When I'm writing React class components, I do the `bind` thing. (I wish decorators had happened / would happen.) `bind` also creates a function object, but the methods are still on the prototype for mocking etc. Happy coding!